# 2012 Toyota Avalon Headlights Hid

Tags: toyota, hid

I have 2012 Toyota Alon with HID headlights. I have had this car for years, but here lately I've noticed the lowbeams are hardly working the start strong but slowly goes to where you can barely see them on the road. They don't flicker or anything and these are the third pair of lights that i have put in. IDK what to replace to make them work but ik its not the bulbs themselves. Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

Ordinarily I'd say dimming headlights were a sign you have a bad alternator, the lights dim as your battery loses charge while driving, however as you are having no issues starting the car this isn't the case.

You probably have a bad ballast or ballasts for your HID light system. A ballast is a power regulator, there should be one for each light. I suspect that when they get hot they are developing issues, dimming is one of the common symptoms of that. You'll need to replace the ballasts. I don't know where they are in your car, but they are usually close to the lights they supply power to.